# Graph construction terminology

Tags: graph-theory

Given graph $G=(V,E)$, is there a graph $H=(U,F)$ where the edges of $H$ are the vertices of $G$ and the vertices of $H$ are the edges of $G$? If $G$ is a complete graph, what is $H$?

How do cycles in a complete graph get mapped in $H$?

Comment: [Line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph)

Comment: Hypergraphs are a generalization of graphs where this switching process (taking the dual) works. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph

Answer (score 1):

No. Not in general. $E$ is a set of unordered pairs of $V$, so switching them can only be done when the vertices have degree 2 (so $G$ is some number of loops).

You could of course make the vertices out of the edges. Then make edges in $H$ whenever the edges in $G$ share a vertex. But that means you'll get multiple edges in $H$ for every vertex in $G$. As pointed out in the comments to the question, this is known as a [line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph).

The other comment above refers to a [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph), which has hyperedges which are sets of any number of vertices, which would be invertible in this way

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Consider a graph G having one vertex, and no edges. Either the empty graph H=({}, {}) is an allowed answer, or you have to create a graph with no vertices, but an edge...